# Stream interface to a file on SFTP server in C# SSH.NET

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, winscp, ssh.net

I am connecting to an SFTP server using SSH.NET and trying to read an image into a stream for displaying it in my web page.

```
SftpClient client = connectToServer(IP,user,pwd); 
string remotePath = client.WorkingDirectory.ToString() + dto.Directory + "/"; 
FileStream fs = new FileStream(remotePath + dto.FileName,FileMode.Open); 
Stream strm = fs;
```

The above code throws an invalid characters exception. I am not sure if the reason for it is because of the filename on the server i.e. all these files are stored with `*` delimiter i.e. `Text1*Text2*Text3.00.png`.

If it is, is there any other way to read the stream?

I have also tried to read from `HttpResponse.OutputStream` but that throws a read/seek invalid exception.

```
HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
Stream strm = response.OutputStream;
```

Are there any other ways to read such image files?
[image]

---

This is the working code code for the same functionality using `FtpWebRequest`.

```
var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverUri);
request.UsePassive = true;
request.UseBinary = true;
request.Credentials =// 
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
response = (FtpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

I am changing it to SFTP using SSH.NET.

Is there a way to get the same output as `GetResponseStream()` with SSH.NET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to obtain `Stream` API to a file on SFTP server, use SSH.NET `SftpClient.Open[Read]`:

```
Stream fs = client.OpenRead(remotePath);
```